# Set focus to UITextField from Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

This should've been asked&answered dozens of time but I can't find anything useful on SO so sorry for a potential duplicate..

**..how can I set up a simple view with just a single `UITextField` to have the text field focus right away when the view is displayed?**

I know this can be done using the view controller but I'm looking for a way to set this up in Interface Builder.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible...

Comment: I think so as well, you might be able to assign something to the `First Responder` in the storyboard, but I am not actually managing to get a connection working.

Comment: Nope. Do it in code. You could subclass `UITextField` add an IBInspectable bool called autoFocus and then if that is checked become first responder. After that you could do everything in IB